# MVC Controller - Http Post map values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass additional data back to the MVC controller, without changing my ViewModel.

Is there a way to do this without using the formcollection?

For example, something like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel item, formvalue a)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. You'll need to know the name/key of the form item you want bound. For example, if it's `<input type="text" name="MyInput" />`, the action can be:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel item, string myInput)
{
}
```

And another idea, you could pass in the entire form collection and then access it:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel item, FormCollection form)
{
    var myInput = form["MyInput"];
}
```